# How to add a root item to a SWT Tree

Tags: java, swt

This is the sample code I'm using to create a `Tree` (`t`) in a `TreeViewer` (`viewer`), where `MasterTreeContentProvider` is a class that implements `ITreeContentProvider`.

```
Tree t = toolkit.createTree(client, SWT.NULL);
GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
gd.heightHint = 20;
gd.widthHint = 100;
t.setLayoutData(gd);
toolkit.paintBordersFor(client);
section.setClient(client);
final SectionPart spart = new SectionPart(section);
managedForm.addPart(spart);
viewer = new TreeViewer(t);
viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() 
{
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) 
    {
        managedForm.fireSelectionChanged(spart, event.getSelection());
    }
});
viewer.setContentProvider(new MasterTreeContentProvider());
viewer.setInput(page.getEditor().getEditorInput());
```

Inside the `MasterTreeContentProvider` class I defined `getElements()` in such a way that it gets the contents (say `Child1, Child2, Child3`).

With the present code it gets displayed in the following way:

```
Child1
Child2
Child3
```

and I would like to look the tree in this way, with the Root as below:

```
Root
|-- Child1
 -- Child2
 -- Child3
```

How and where do I add a root element to this tree?

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to implement `getElements()` in your `MasterTreeContentProvider`. You have to implement `getChildren()` to build the hierarchy you want to show. The `Object` you pass to those methods should be a custom class which represents this hierarchy. See [Eclipse JFace Tree - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJFaceTree/article.html) for a good example.

Comment: Implemented the getChildren() method and obtained the desired structure. Now, I'm trying to add new children to the tree. How do i update the tree viewer?

Comment: @karthikkonduri: just call `refresh` on your viewer. If you have further questions you should post them as new questions instead of extending this one...